# How to see Test result in Codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I want to have a test stage in codepipeline. to do that I create a codedeploy as a stage of codepipeline, the appspec.yml is:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: test
    destination: /mycodedeploy/test
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: test/run_test.sh
    - timeout: 3600
```

the code deploy completes successfully, except I do not see test result of test/run_test.sh in AWS console. 
Where can I see the test result like?

```
"Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to see the logs from your script in the AWS console unless you configure your instance to publish the logs to CloudWatch.

You should be able to see the logs on the host here: `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`. If you don't publish them to CloudWatch, you'll have to manually look on the host. [Here's more information on CodeDeploy agent logging.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html)

Comment: Thanks EmptyArsenal, I can see it after I install cloud watch agent in the ec2. Thank you!